# NameError: name 'd' is not defined in Python list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, nameerror

Trying to run the following code in python 3.7:

```
date_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d['date'], '%Y-%m-%d') for d in date_settings and d['date'] != None]
```

This is the resulting error, can someone please clarify to me why this list comprehension cant see its own variable?

```
date_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d['date'], '%Y-%m-%d') for d in date_settings and d['date'] != None]
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

here is the inputed array:

```
[{'date': '2020-05-08', 'changed_at': '2020-05-07T20:35:07.854Z'}, {'date': '2020-05-09', 'changed_at': '2020-05-07T20:35:40.604Z'}, {'date': '2020-05-10', 'changed_at': '2020-05-07T20:35:42.936Z'}]
```

Comment: `for d in date_settings and d['date'] != None`—You mean `if`, not `and`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your comprehension, where you wrote

```
for d in date_settings and d['date'] != None
```

you should have `if`, not `and`.

As you currently have it, the comprehension is trying to understand the expression

```
date_settings and d['date'] != None
```

as something that `d` should iterate through, which is why it doesn't know what `d` is supposed to mean here.

Comment: Thank you worked like a charm, don't know how I missed that.